# How to delete files in OneDrive Microsoft 365?

Tags: cloud, onedrive

I use a company's Microsoft 365 cloud yet I don't have permissions to delete my files.  Is there a workaround for this or a third party tools that can bypass the permissions? I do a global search in onedrive by CreatedBy and it lists all files I own but no delete functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to delete OneDrive files that you own, there is likely a data loss prevention policy at work prohibiting you from doing so. Even if you managed to delete a file with a third-party tool, your Microsoft 365 Administrator can retain/restore these files and will likely be alerted to the fact that this has occurred through the 365 Compliance Center.

I am not an attorney, but I would encourage you to research the possible legal ramifications of circumventing an organization's data loss prevention policies:

[NACDL: Computer Fraud and Abuse Act (CFAA)](https://www.nacdl.org/Landing/ComputerFraudandAbuseAct)